# Post Image With parametrs in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am using NSURLConnection to integtarte the Web-service.

My code is as follow:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Sign_Up_URL];
     NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vimage=%@&@"vFname=%@&vLname=%@&vEmail=%@&vPassword=%@&vDeviceType=%@&vDeviceToken=%@",image_data,txt_first.text,txt_last.text,txt_email.text,txt_password.text,@"IOS",@"safasf423526dgdsgdsg"];
     [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [urlRequest setValue:header_filed forHTTPHeaderField:@"X_API_KEY"];
     [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
     NSData *data,
     NSError *connectionError) {
     // handle response
     [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
     NSDictionary *json_response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     NSLog(@"%@",json_response);
     //  [self login_response:json_response];
     }];
```

**But How can I upload a image with this parameter?**

[Also Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598044/how-to-send-image-and-text-together-using-nsmutableurlrequest)

**Help for this.**

Comment: you will have to convert your image in NSData , then you will have to upload that data with your parameter.

Comment: @NiravPatel, thanks for your reply! I already tried with converting NSdata but not get successful result.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c for solution.May be it is useful..

Comment: Are you getting any error or response ?

Comment: Have you tried with ASIHTTPRequest for posting image data with other parameters?..@user2893370

Comment: may i know why -1 for my answer. i gave you a list of answers i answered before which matches your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Please read Article : http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html, and used ContentType : **Multipart/from-data**;

for your reference :

```
NSString *boundary = @"YOUR_BOUNDARY_STRING";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", self.message.photoKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n%@", self.message.message] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user\"\r\n\r\n%d", 1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Hope this will help,  Please update me if you have getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

By using NSURLConnection you can do like below

```
NSData* fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:image_data];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Sign_Up_URL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"]; // This is important! //NSURLConnection is very sensitive to format.
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
 
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"VFname\"; filename=\"thefilename\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:fileData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param2\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:self.emailtextfield.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param3\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:self.passwordtextfield.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:self.vlnametextfield.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

(OR using ASIHTTPRequest you can do it as below)

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:Sign_Up_URL];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request setPostValue:vnamelabel.textforKey:@"VFname"];

    [request setPostValue:emaillabel.text forKey:@"vEmail"];

    [request setPostValue:passwordlabel.text forKey:@"vPassword"];

    [request setPostValue:devicetypelabel.text forKey:@"vDeviceType"];

     [request addData:self.imagedata withFileName:@"image.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"vimage"];
     //----------------------
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score -1):

Hi Follow below links for my answers

[Upload image to server with iOS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900064/upload-image-to-server-with-ios-not-working/20900407#20900407)

[Trouble Passing Variables to PHP Script on Image Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698986/trouble-passing-variables-to-php-script-on-image-upload/20699710#20699710)

[How do post Json and Image to server for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924342/how-do-post-json-and-image-to-server-for-ios/21925520#21925520)

[Send JSON request with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038551/send-json-request-with-ios/22039350#22039350)

[how to GET or POST multipart data request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061478/how-to-get-or-post-multipart-data-request-in-php/22062088#22062088)

[PHP to Edit XML, POSTed from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550216/php-to-edit-xml-posted-from-ios/22550671#22550671)

Hope this will help